# Не могу использовать библиотеку Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

Делаю банальное приложение на C# для заполнения форм в документах Word. Там пока всё очень просто: есть текстовое поле и кнопка. По нажатию кнопки программа извлекает текст из текстового поля и если оно не было пустым то программа должна вставить этот  текст во вкладку в Word-файле. Но как только код (который я пишу и тестирую в Visual Studio 2019) доходит до открытия приложения Word через строку `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();` то у меня студия стопает выполнение и выскакивает вот такая вот ошибка :

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. Не удается найти указанный файл."
```

Вот код, дальше проблемной строки не писал, нет смысла

```
using System; 
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace FormFiller
{
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string text = textBox1.Text;
            if (text != "")
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Поле не может быть пустым!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Перепробовал вроде бы всё что знаю и что нашёл в интернете. Сбрасывал эту библиотеку через NuGet (через неё же и устанавливал) до версии 12.0.0, скачивал всякие .NET SDK 4.x, скачивал Visual Studio Tools for Office, переустанавливал эту библиотеку, но ничего не выходит. В чём может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста.

Доп. информация:
Microsoft Office 2013 у меня стоит

P.S.
Во вкладке ошибок у меня выскакивает вот такое предупреждение:

```
NU1701  Пакет "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 12.0.0" был восстановлен с помощью ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8", а не целевой платформы проекта ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1". Этот пакет может быть не полностью совместим с вашим проектом.
```

Я заходил в свойства проекта открывал вкладку приложение и пытался поставить целевую рабочую среду на какой-нибудь .NET Core 4.x.x но мне предлагает только .NET Core 3.0 и 3.1, хотя Пакеты SDK для различных версий .NET Framework 4.x.x у меня установлены. Возможно, эта ошибка связана с моей проблемой, кто знает подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Так, вся проблема была в том что я выбрал неправильный шаблон для проекта. Я выбрал WPF .NET App Core где естественно поддерживалось именно Core. А надо выбирать Приложение WPF .NET Framework. Там мне сразу предложили  и версию фреймворка, и пропало это предупреждение. Ну и проблема пропала.

Comment: Для информации, в .NET Core тоже можно использовать Office.Interop: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/extensions/ExcelDemo Только нужно вручную добавлять COMReference в файл проекта.